# Gas estimation errored with the following message，execution reverted

Tags: solidity, remix, gas

I got the "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?" in remix while using the `drawWinner` function

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity  >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 * @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
 */
contract firire {
    
    function withdrawal(uint256 amount) public {
        require(amount <= 100000000000000000, "error");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    }

    fallback() external payable {}

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it’s an error with the syntax. I’m unsure why you’ve denoted the `withdrawal` functionality as payable, as it isn’t intending to receive ether or modify any state variables. This would likely result in a gas estimation error. Try removing the `payable` declaration.